Issue with count API key creation
hope you're having a great learning experience. I've been trying to integrate CountAPI into a website hosted on GitLab Pages. However, I'm finding it challenging to generate the CountAPI key.
The documentation seems very straightforward. The docs suggest using "https://api.countapi.xyz/create?namespace=mysite.com&value=42" to create the key. I modified it to "https://api.countapi.xyz/create?namespace=kshitij_test&value=0". Despite trying multiple times, I keep getting a 504 error.
Is countapi still maintained and actively used by people? If yes, where am I missing something?
Are there any alternative methods to achieve this when we don't have a domain?

I am having a similar issue with the api, all calls return 504. Have not used it before so maybe I am approaching it wrong

Hey @FatFrank, it seems like we're on the same page. I ended up using a lambda function to count the number of visits, which interacts with a database storing a value. Here's how it works: when someone visits my website, a JavaScript function triggers an API. The API (Function as a Service) fetches data from the database, increments it, stores it, and then sends it to the client. It might seem a bit overkill, but for now, this approach seems to be working.
